# Why are Func<> delegates so much slower

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-core, benchmarking

I was in the process of moving repeated arithmetic code into reusable chunks using funcs but when I ran a simple test to benchmark if it will be any slower, I was surprised that it is twice as slow.

Why is evaluating the expression twice as slow

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Exporters;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Loggers;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Calculations>();

            var logger = ConsoleLogger.Default;
            MarkdownExporter.Console.ExportToLog(summary, logger);

            Console.WriteLine(summary);
        }
    }

    public class Calculations
    {
        public Random RandomGeneration = new Random();

        [Benchmark]
        public void CalculateNormal()
        {
           var s =  RandomGeneration.Next() * RandomGeneration.Next();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void CalculateUsingFunc()
        {
            Calculate(() => RandomGeneration.Next() * RandomGeneration.Next());
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public int Calculate(Func<int> expr)
        {
            return expr();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the benchmark:
[image]

Comment: Did CalculateNormal get optimized? Since you aren't using `s` at all, the optimizer could have removed the whole line?

Comment: Interesting point, I will rerun with it being used

Comment: Don't know, if it makes any difference, but I would guess that you won't use anonymous lambdas in your real implementation. So you should maybe make a private static method and provide this to your calculate method. Maybe the runtime can optimize that better?

Comment: Could you include the resulting IL in your question?

Comment: If `CalculateNormal` is faster, can you talk us through why you don't just use `CalculateNormal` (or the equivalent)?

Comment: In future, please include `using` directives in your example code - I've added them in now, but it would have saved me a few minutes of time if you'd included them from the start.

Comment: Lambdas in C# have an overhead of allocation.

Comment: It is not twice as slow, creating and invoking a delegate has a *fixed* overhead cost that does not depend on what the invoked method does.  Standard optimizations do not apply, no AggressiveInlining, at JIT compile-time the jitter does not yet know what method is going to be called so cannot inline it.  It doesn't even know if the method is instance or static, big issue for x64 (instance is best).  It merely looks twice as slow by accident since the invoked method does very little.  Notably code that almost never requires optimization.

Comment: apparently for c# 9 - they are adding `static` lambdas which would help in this scenario

Comment: @DanielA.White: It would help in terms of diagnosing it - it wouldn't help in terms of the performance itself. (Hopefully that's already what you meant.)

Comment: @JonSkeet wouldn't it help reduce the allocations? i thought it lifted it out to be reusable..

Comment: @DanielA.White: It would if it were applicable to this case, but it's not: "As a result, locals, parameters, and `this` from the enclosing scope are not available within a static anonymous function." The OP's lambda expression uses `this` (implicitly) so I'd expect they'd get a compile-time error instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet that makes sense - i missed that nuance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're creating a new delegate object on *every* call. It's not surprising that that has a fair amount of overhead.

If you either use a lambda expression that doesn't capture `this` or any local variables (in which case the compiler can cache it in a static field) or if you explicitly create a single instance and store that in a field yourself, most of the overhead goes away.

Here's a modified version of your test:

```cs
public class Calculations
{
    public Random RandomGeneration = new Random();
    private Func<int> exprField;
    
    public Calculations()
    {
        exprField = () => RandomGeneration.Next() * RandomGeneration.Next();
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void CalculateNormal()
    {
       var s =  RandomGeneration.Next() * RandomGeneration.Next();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void CalculateUsingFunc()
    {
        Calculate(() => RandomGeneration.Next() * RandomGeneration.Next());
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void CalculateUsingFuncField()
    {
        Calculate(exprField);
    }

    
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public int Calculate(Func<int> expr)
    {
        return expr();
    }
}
```

And the results on my machine:

```
|                  Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|------------------------ |---------:|---------:|---------:|
|         CalculateNormal | 27.61 ns | 0.438 ns | 0.388 ns |
|      CalculateUsingFunc | 48.74 ns | 1.009 ns | 0.894 ns |
| CalculateUsingFuncField | 32.53 ns | 0.698 ns | 0.717 ns |
```

So there's still a *bit* of overhead, but much, much less than before.

Comment: I blame @EricLippert that we have to deal with this, and that the compiler doesn't optimize without the overhead, specially in cases where the only captured variable is the "magic" this.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, how do you capture the magic 'this' keyword here so to avoid me storing this in a variable?

Comment: @RickyG you already are - the `RandomGeneration` is accessed like `this.RandomGeneration`

Comment: @DanielA.White - but even if `RandomGeneration` would be declared as `static` a `this` will be captured or?

Comment: @RandRandom i dont think so. and `Random` isn't thread safe so a `static Random` would be discouraged.

Comment: @RickyG: The point is to *avoid* capturing `this` - but basically if you're accessing anything that uses something in the instance (`RandomGeneration`) then the delegate has to be cached on a per-instance basis, or created fresh each time.

Comment: @DanielA.White - seems like you are correct, I kinda had in mind that no matter what you are doing you will always capture `this` since thats how lambda works, unless you are storing them in a variable and re-use that variable... seems I had wrong information, though I never really understood, why a lamba just doesnt simply get compiled into a method and the method being used without the overhead, though I totally lack the background knowledge of why/why not, it just feels "strange" that you are encouraged to use lamba in any linq operation, but performance/allocation sucks

Comment: @RandRandom: Performance doesn't "suck" - you just need to be aware of what's going on and account for that. In many cases - e.g. usually in LINQ - you create a single instance of a delegate and execute it multiple times. That's not what happens in your benchmark, where each delegate is executed a single time... which yes, leads to overhead. If you don't want the extra flexibility of being able to encapsulate the behaviour in an object, then just call the method directly...